# Two level sorting in a nested tuple of nested lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, tuples

I have a deeply nested tuple of nested lists as follows:

```
ip = (array([[[ 50,  73]],
       [[ 50, 107]],
       [[ 55, 108]],
       [[ 55, 121]],
       [[978,  87]],
       [[977,  86]],
       [[977,  73]]], dtype=int32), 

array([[[ 669,    3]],
       [[ 668,    4]],
       [[ 667,    4]],
       [[1033,   71]],
       [[1035,   69]],
       [[1035,    4]],
       [[ 848,    4]],
       [[ 847,    3]],
       [[ 813,    3]],
       [[ 718,    4]],
       [[ 717,    3]]], dtype=int32), 

array([[[ 17,   3]],
       [[ 16,   4]],
       [[  0,   4]],
       [[  0,  49]],
       [[197,  49]],
       [[197,   8]],
       [[ 84,   4]],
       [[ 83,   3]]], dtype=int32))
```

The length of the main tuple in above example is 3. I want to **perform a 2 level sorting** on the above structure. First I want to **sort all the 3 elements in the main list in increasing order based on the first value of nested list**. So in the above case the **third element** will come first as it has the **lowest value** of the first element i.e. `0`. Second should be the **first element** as it has the **second lowest value** of `50`and last should be the **third element** as it has the **third lowest value** of `1035`. The output of the first level sorting should be:

```
op = (array([[[ 17,   3]],
       [[ 16,   4]],
       [[  0,   4]],
       [[  0,  49]],
       [[197,  49]],
       [[197,   8]],
       [[ 84,   4]],
       [[ 83,   3]]], dtype=int32),

array([[[ 50,  73]],
       [[ 50, 107]],
       [[ 55, 108]],
       [[ 55, 121]],
       [[978,  87]],
       [[977,  86]],
       [[977,  73]]], dtype=int32), 

array([[[ 669,    3]],
       [[ 668,    4]],
       [[ 667,    4]],
       [[1033,   71]],
       [[1035,   69]],
       [[1035,    4]],
       [[ 848,    4]],
       [[ 847,    3]],
       [[ 813,    3]],
       [[ 718,    4]],
       [[ 717,    3]]], dtype=int32), 
)
```

Now I want to perform the same sorting again on the above `op` but instead of the first value of the nested list I want to **sort based on the second value** of the nested list. So now the final output would be as follows:

```
final_op = (array([[[ 17,   3]],
       [[ 16,   4]],
       [[  0,   4]],
       [[  0,  49]],
       [[197,  49]],
       [[197,   8]],
       [[ 84,   4]],
       [[ 83,   3]]], dtype=int32), 

array([[[ 669,    3]],
       [[ 668,    4]],
       [[ 667,    4]],
       [[1033,   71]],
       [[1035,   69]],
       [[1035,    4]],
       [[ 848,    4]],
       [[ 847,    3]],
       [[ 813,    3]],
       [[ 718,    4]],
       [[ 717,    3]]], dtype=int32),

array([[[ 50,  73]],
       [[ 50, 107]],
       [[ 55, 108]],
       [[ 55, 121]],
       [[978,  87]],
       [[977,  86]],
       [[977,  73]]], dtype=int32)
)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sorted` on your `tuple` and specify the item using the `key` parameter

First sort

```
ip = sorted(ip, key=lambda x: x[0][0][0])
print(ip)

[array([[[ 17,   3]],
       [[ 16,   4]],
       [[  0,   4]],
       [[  0,  49]],
       [[197,  49]],
       [[197,   8]],
       [[ 84,   4]],
       [[ 83,   3]]]),
array([[[ 50,  73]],
       [[ 50, 107]],
       [[ 55, 108]],
       [[ 55, 121]],
       [[978,  87]],
       [[977,  86]],
       [[977,  73]]]),
array([[[ 669,    3]],
       [[ 668,    4]],
       [[ 667,    4]],
       [[1033,   71]],
       [[1035,   69]],
       [[1035,    4]],
       [[ 848,    4]],
       [[ 847,    3]],
       [[ 813,    3]],
       [[ 718,    4]],
       [[ 717,    3]]])]
```

And the second sort

```
ip = sorted(ip, key=lambda x: x[0][0][1])
print(ip)

[array([[[ 17,   3]],
       [[ 16,   4]],
       [[  0,   4]],
       [[  0,  49]],
       [[197,  49]],
       [[197,   8]],
       [[ 84,   4]],
       [[ 83,   3]]]),
array([[[ 669,    3]],
       [[ 668,    4]],
       [[ 667,    4]],
       [[1033,   71]],
       [[1035,   69]],
       [[1035,    4]],
       [[ 848,    4]],
       [[ 847,    3]],
       [[ 813,    3]],
       [[ 718,    4]],
       [[ 717,    3]]])
array([[[ 50,  73]],
       [[ 50, 107]],
       [[ 55, 108]],
       [[ 55, 121]],
       [[978,  87]],
       [[977,  86]],
       [[977,  73]]])]
```

If you want it back as `tuple` just do `tuple(ip)`